# How to merge two select statements into one with a single row and custom column names

Tags: sql-server

I've got a `SELECT` statement to summarize the size of all backupjobs from a specific day for a specific server.

```
SELECT 
    bck_servername,
    SUM ((CAST(bck_size AS DECIMAL)) / 1024.0 / 1024.0 / 1024.0) AS sizeGB
FROM 
    [dbo].[BackupJobs] 
WHERE 
    [bck_timestamp] LIKE '%0901'
GROUP BY 
    bck_servername
```

| bck_servername | sizeGB |
| --- | --- |
| server1 | 270.62345664 |

The result looks good, but I want something more. I want to use the same `SELECT` but for the `%0801` date filter and merge it with the first result so that I get a single row with `bck_servername`, `sizeGB` and `sizeGB_old` (where `sizeGB_old` is the size of %0801). I tried it with UNION but I got 2 rows instead of one.

```
SELECT 
    bck_servername, 
    SUM ((CAST(bck_size AS DECIMAL)) / 1024.0 / 1024.0 / 1024.0) AS sizeGB
FROM 
    [dbo].[BackupJobs] 
WHERE 
    [bck_timestamp] LIKE '%0901'
GROUP BY 
    bck_servername

UNION

SELECT 
    bck_servername,
    SUM ((CAST(bck_size AS DECIMAL)) / 1024.0 / 1024.0 / 1024.0) AS sizeGB
FROM 
    [dbo].[BackupJobs] 
WHERE 
    [bck_timestamp] LIKE '%0801'
GROUP BY 
    bck_servername
```

What I get:

| bck_servername | sizeGB |
| --- | --- |
| server1 | 270.62345664 |
| server1 | 278.44533446 |

What I want:

| bck_servername | sizeGB | sizeGB_Old |
| --- | --- | --- |
| server1 | 270.62345664 | 278.44533446 |

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance

PS: the value in `bck_size` is a string, the datatype is a `varchar`. If there is a nice way to get just 2 decimals, that would be a nice bonus.

Comment: I assume your column bck_timestamp is varchar or similar? Why are you storing dates a strings? Why not store that as a date and then you don't have to use nonSARGable predicates with leading wildcards. You also are casting a column to a decimal but you don't specify the scale or precision. What would really help here is to provide the table definitions and some sample data.

Comment: It's always interesting to see a database getting _smaller_ over time. The opposite is much more common.

Comment: I'm using varchar for pretty much everything, because I have no clue what I'm doing and therefore its much easier to handle everything as a string. My dates are all yyyymmdd as a string, so I never have to think about date conversions from american systems to european or from "." delimiter to "," or whatever different formats there are. The same goes for all the other fields.  I still can sort or search my dates so until now I never had a problem. There are propably hundreds of reasons why this is not a good way of setting up a database but its just a small project and it just has to work.

Comment: I already tried to specify the scale and precision while casting but it always ended in an arithmetic overflow. I figured I will just cut the string via php or javascript after the export because fortunately  I do not need that grade of precision, so there is no point in rounding the number, cutting everything after the first two decimals is more than precise enough.

Comment: @ddl sounds resonable, but then you suddenly change some client and start using another style of decimals or date setting, and will be writing a question on why a cast doesn't work anymore. Use correct datatypes and you will have much less problems even while you develop. Plus, the developers that come after you won't have to curse you :)

Comment: "its much easier to handle everything as a string.". It's really not. Really. You're causing MUCH more trouble for yourself using varchar for dates and numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done using the conditional aggregation :

```
SELECT bck_servername,
SUM ( CASE WHEN [bck_timestamp] LIKE '%0901' 
           THEN bck_size/1024.0/1024.0/1024.0
           END
    ) as sizeGB,
SUM ( CASE WHEN [bck_timestamp] LIKE '%0801' 
           THEN bck_size/1024.0/1024.0/1024.0
           END
    ) as sizeGB_Old
FROM [BackupJobs] 
WHERE [bck_timestamp] LIKE '%0901' or [bck_timestamp] LIKE '%0801'
GROUP BY bck_servername
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked like a charm. I only had to cast bck_size as decimal, otherwise I got an Arithmetic overflow error. (which is propably not your fault, but mine because of the datatypes I'm using.

Comment: Glad to hear I could help you :)

Answer (score 0):

`UNION` results in a relation that contains all records from the first query and all records from the second query, so, given your query, the behavior you experienced is actually expected. However, you can do a join of the two results:

```
SELECT bck_servername, t1.sizeGB AS sizeGB, t2. sizeGB as sizeGB_old
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        bck_servername, 
        SUM ((CAST(bck_size AS DECIMAL)) / 1024.0 / 1024.0 / 1024.0) AS sizeGB
    FROM 
        [dbo].[BackupJobs] 
    WHERE 
        [bck_timestamp] LIKE '%0901'
    GROUP BY 
        bck_servername
) t1
JOIN
(
    SELECT 
        bck_servername,
        SUM ((CAST(bck_size AS DECIMAL)) / 1024.0 / 1024.0 / 1024.0) AS sizeGB
    FROM 
        [dbo].[BackupJobs] 
    WHERE 
        [bck_timestamp] LIKE '%0801'
    GROUP BY 
        bck_servername 
) t2
ON t1.bck_servername = t2.bck_servername;
```